# Allow only specific special characters with 3-15 length of digits regex

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

This is what is have tried

> `^(?=.(?=.?[+-,() ]))(?:\D*\d){3,15}\D*$`

a regex that follows the following parameters:
Minimum length of digits not including special characters: 3 
The maximum length of digits not including special characters: 15 
The total number of digits has to be between 3,15 
Space and Special characters allowed: '+', '-', '(', ')', ' '
No alphabets allowed
 The length of the string is determined by the number of digits. 
There can be n number of special characters in the string, but the length of the digit should not exceed 15.

The acceptable responses are
`((((((((((12345` (Valid)
 `123----------------` (Valid)
 `123-5678-9123456` (Valid) 
`(((((` (Invalid) 
`((((((((((123`(Valid) 
 122!!!!!(invalid)

The regex used here is accepting the response when at least one special is present. However, if anything is present beside  `'+', '-', '(', ')', ' '` and digits, it's should not match

Comment: So something like `^(?:[(),+ -]*\d){3,15}[(),+ -]*$` should work maybe.

Comment: Is this a valid or an invalid character sequence ?.. `--1---2-3----------`. Or in other words; are the digits to be applied consecutively with a minimum digit count of three as with the OP's examples or can the minimum amount of digits be applied somehow interrupted as shown with this comment?

Comment: @just_curious ... anyhow, already the verification (all the OP's validation criteria have to be met) of `123-5678-9123456` can not be covered by a regex alone.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you not to try to do all the work with a single regular expression, but to break the check into multiple operations.

A complex regular expression is extremely difficult to maintain. Also, as far as I know, it's not posible to have a quantifier constraints for patter delimieted by some other pattern like `(\d+(:ignore-this\D*)){3,15}`. So I'm afraid you won't be able to reach the goal with a single regex.

But you can make your validation function like this and use it instead of regex `test`:

```
let targetList = [
    '123', 
    '((((((((((12345', 
    '123----------------', 
    '12-------',
    '123-5678-9123456', 
    '(((((', 
    '((((((((((123', 
    '122!!!!!'
];

function isValid(target) {
    let hasInvalidChars = /[^\d\+\-() ]/
    let hasSpecialChars = /[\+\-() ]/
    let stripNonDigits = /\D+/g

    let digitsCount = target.replace(stripNonDigits, '').length; 

    return (
        !hasInvalidChars.test(target)
        && hasSpecialChars.test(target)
        && digitsCount >= 3
        && digitsCount <= 15
    );
}

for (let target of targetList) {
    console.log(target, isValid(target));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?:[(),+ -]*\d){3,15}[(),+ -]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GTPKfg/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[(),+ -]*\d){3,15}` - three to fifteen sequences of a `(`, `)`, `,`, `+`, space or `-` char and then any digit
- `[(),+ -]*` - zero or more chars from the `(`, `)`, `,`, `+`, space or `-` charset.
- `$` - end of string.